# Правильно ли расставлены запятые? 1

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот, вставная-конструкция

Однако (**,**) не имея особого желания говорить с ним -- только Бог свидетель этого нежелания (**,**) -- он предложил незамедлительно приступить к делу.

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в данном случае?
На стилистику не смотрите, предложение вырвано из контекста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректно: Однако, не имея особого желания говорить с ним — только Бог свидетель этого нежелания, — он предложил незамедлительно приступить к делу.

В вашем примере вставная конструкция примыкает к предшествующему деепричастному обороту, и запятая ставится после всей конструкции. 
Ср.: **Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — а это с ним изредка происходит, — он пытается стать рационалистом.** *— вставное предложение примыкает к предшествующей придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, и запятая ставится после всей конструкции;*
***Он встал и, прихрамывая — он был на протезе, — подошёл к окну (Кав.) —*** *вставному предложению предшествует деепричастие, и запятая ставится, после всей этой конструкции;*

> После "однако" стоит запятая, так как далее следует обособленный оборот.

См.: [Розенталь, Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку. Орфография. Пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125)